# Select returns empty results on remote MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database on a remote machine(Ubuntu) that I want to access through my local machine (Windows). I understand that to do so I have `GRANT` access to my MySQL user.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

I am using JAVA JDBC to access my MySQL databases. I am able to perform `INSERT` query, however, the `SELECT` query returns an empty result set.

```
public class MySqlConnector {

    Connection db;
    String user     = null;
    String password = null;
    String dbName   = null; 
    String componentsTable;

    public MySqlConnector(){
        this.user     = "user";     // MySQL Userid
        this.password = "password"; // MySQL Password
        this.dbName   = "database"; // Database Name
    }   

    public MySqlConnector(String dbName, String user, String password){
        if(dbName != null){
            this.dbName = dbName;
        }
        if(user != null){
            this.user = user;
        }
        if(password != null){
            this.password = password;
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection(){
        try {
            // JDBC Driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            System.out.println(dbName + " " + user + " " + password);
            db =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://IPADDRESS:PORT/"+dbName,user,password);
            System.out.println("Connect Established");
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return db;
    }

    public void insertQuery(String query){
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = (Statement)db.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate(query);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ResultSet executeQuery(String query){
        Statement statement= null;
        ResultSet resultset= null;
        try {
        statement = (Statement) db.createStatement();
        statement.executeQuery(query);
        resultset = statement.getResultSet ();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultset;
    }
    public void closeConnection() throws SQLException{
        db.close();
    }
}
```

In my servlet when I query

```
MySqlConnector mysql = new MySqlConnector();
mysql.getConnection();
mysql.insertQuery("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(10)");
mysql.closeConnection();
```

Works beautifully. However, executeQuery return empty.

```
MySqlConnector mysql = new MySqlConnector();
mysql.getConnection();
ResultSet result = mysql.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name");
mysql.closeConnection();
```

Any suggestions or anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was in the other part of the code, that is not listed here. There were two things that went wrong -

1. Session variable initialized to null - got confused with `NullPointerException`
2. When I reading a particular column from `ResultSet` I wrote incorrect column name, therefore received an illegal access.

Thanks everyone for viewing my question and for writing answers/comments.

Answer (score -2):

I think the `Resultset` query must be:

```
Resultset result = mysql.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name");
```